# Elasticsearch Synonyms - How is precedence determined?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, synonym

Say I have a synonym file with just the two synonym lines below

```
ft , synonym_1
10 ft , synonym_2
```

When I use this file in an analyzer and analyze the word "10 ft" I get the following:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "10"
    },
    {
      "token": "ft"
    },
    {
      "token": "synonym_2",
    }
  ]
}
```

synonym_1 doesn't appear, even though "ft" matched a token in the analyzed text. Is this because of some precedence with single tokens and phrases? Does "10 ft" match *more* of the analyzed text and therefore it's the only synonym that takes effect? Is there some way to get the first synonym to work in this case?

Note: I'm using a whitespace tokenizer and analyzing the text "30 ft" gives me synonym_1. It's only when "10 ft" appears exactly that the first synonym is broken.

```
"simplified_analyzer": {
  "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "stemmer",
      "synonyms",
      "edge_ngrams",
      "remove_duplicates"
  ],
  "char_filter" => ["remove_html", "remove_non_alphanumeric"],
  "tokenizer" => "whitespace"
}
```

Do I have to use a second synonym filter to handle single words?

Comment: Can you add your `synonym analyzer` to the question? But yes, the synonym is considered as the entire word. So technically, the answer to your question `Do I have to use a second synonym filter to handle single words?` would be Yes. In your case - `ft` and `10 ft` are two synonyms. The whitespace tokenizer applies to the indexed data and not the synonym file.

Comment: Shoot. I was hoping I wouldn't have to use two synonym files, but it seems that's the simplest way to resolve this.


I did an "explain": true when running this and it all came down to the synonym step. My analyzer has some other steps to handle lower casing and stemming and a couple char_filters but they didn't affect the problem.